# Internal method in Python -- unable to access to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wonder, why do I have the error of `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment` or `NameError: global name 'i' is not defined` in the following code:

```
def method1():
  i = 0
  def _method1():
    # global i -- the same error
    i += 1
    print 'i=', i

  # i = 0 -- the same error
  _method1()

method1()
```

How do I get rid of it? `i` should not be visible outside of `method1()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this in py2x is to pass the variable itself to the internal method, in py3x
this has been fixed and you can use `nonlocal` statement there.

The error is raised because functions are objects too and are evaluated during their definition, and during definition as soon as python sees `i += 1` (which is equivalent to `i = i + 1`) it thinks that `i` is a local variable inside that function. But, when the function is actually called it fails to find any value for the `i` (on the RHS ) locally and thus the error is raised.

```
def method1():
  i = 0
  def _method1(i):
    i += 1
    print 'i=', i
    return i     #return the updated value

  i=_method1(i)  #update i
  print i

method1()
```

or use a function attribute:

```
def method1():
  method1.i = 0       #create a function attribute
  def _method1():
    method1.i += 1
    print 'i=', method1.i

  _method1()

method1()
```

For py3x:

```
def method1():
  i =0 
  def _method1():
    nonlocal i  
    i += 1
    print ('i=', i)
  _method1()

method1()
```

Comment: You might want to mention that he/she was trying to create a closure and how that's achieved in python.